# What is the difference between cv2.addWeighted and numpy mean, in this case?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

Suppose I have two OpenCV (python package `cv2`) loaded grayscale images `img1` and `img2`, both of same dimensions. Now, I wish to take the mean of both `img1` and `img2`. Here are two ways to do it:

```
# Method 1
mean = (img1 * 0.5) + (img2 * 0.5)

# Method 2
mean = cv2.addWeighted(img1,0.5,img2,0.5,0)
```

However, `mean` is visually different in both methods, when I display them using `cv2.imshow`. Why is this so?

Comment: Are you sure img1 and img2 have possible ranges of 0 to 1?

Comment: Also, what is the full package name of cv2? Hard to find documentation if we don't know what it is.

Comment: @topher217: `img1` and `img2` are 8-bit unsigned integers, so they are in [0,255]. `cv2` stands for the python implementation of OpenCV (the full package name itself is `cv2`): https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_setup/py_intro/py_intro.html. Sorry, I forgot to mention that.

Comment: Ah, I got the error! The issue is that `cv2.imshow` expects images to be in the range [0,1]. Pixels greater than 1 are set to 255.

Comment: Can you expand on that and provide an answer to your own question? How did you convert `mean` from an average of ranges 0 -> 255 to one of 0 -> 1 that cv2.imshow would accept? Was Method 1 resulting in values over 255 (clipping), while Method 2 was not?

Comment: @topher217: Done! Thanks for the help! Your first comment helped me resolve the issue. :)

Comment: other than that, in case of efficiency, `cv2.addWeighted` function is highly optimized and much faster than the manual numpy multiplication

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am glad that you have found a working solution to your problem, but this seems to be a workaround. The real reason for this behaviour lies somewhere else. The problem here is that `mean = (img1 * 0.5) + (img2 * 0.5)` is returning a matrix with `float32` data type which contains values in range `0.0 - 255.0`. You can verify this by using `print mean.dtype`. Since the new matrix values have been converted to float unintentionally, we can revert this operation by using `(img_1 * 0.5 + img_2 * 0.5).astype("uint8")`. In case of `cv2.addWeighted()` it automatically returns you a matrix of data type `uint8` and all things would work fine.

My concern is with the conclusion that you have drawn:

> The issue is that the `cv2.imshow()` method used to display images,
>   expects your image arrays to be normalized, i.e. in the range [0,1].

`cv2.imshow()` works just fine with range of `[0-255]` and `[0.0-1.0]`, but the issue arises when you pass a matrix whose values are in range `[0-255]`, but the dtype is `float32` instead of `uint8`.

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own question, to help others who get confused by this:

Both methods 1 and 2 yield the same result. You can verify this by writing the `mean` image to disk using `cv2.imwrite`. The issue is not with the methods.

The issue is that the `cv2.imshow` method used to display images, expects your image arrays to be normalized, i.e. in the range [0,1]. In my case, both the image arrays are 8-bit unsigned integers and so, its pixel values are in the range [0,255]. Since `mean` is an average of the two arrays, its pixel values are also in the range [0,255]. So when I passed `mean` to `cv2.imshow`, pixels having values greater than 1 were interpreted as having a value of 255, resulting in vastly different visuals.

The solution is to normalize `mean` before passing it to `cv2.imshow`:

```
# Method 1
mean = (img1 * 0.5) + (img2 * 0.5)

# Method 2
mean = cv2.addWeighted(img1,0.5,img2,0.5,0)

# Note that the division by 255 results in the image array values being squeezed to [0,1].

cv2.imshow("Averaged", mean/255.)
```